# How is the "empty string" sequence represented under the hood in Java?

Tags: java, jvm

Throughout my career I've often seen calls like this:

```
if( "".equals(foo) ) { //do stuff };
```

How is the empty string understood in terms of data in the lower-levels of Java?

Specifically, by "Lower-levels of Java" I'm referring to the actual contents of memory or some C/C++ construct being used to represent the `""` sequence, rather than high-level implementations in Java.

I had previously checked the Java Language Specification which lead me to [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5), and noting that the "empty string" wasn't really given much more definition than that, this is then what led to the head-scratching.

I then ran `javap` on some various classes trying to tease out an answer through bytecode, but the behavior in regards to "How is the machine dealing with the sequence `""` wasn't really any more clear.  Having then excluded byte code and Java code I then posted the question here, hoping that someone would shed some light on the issue from a lower-level perspective.

Comment: Have you looked at the source for the [String](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java) class and followed the [String()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.%3Cinit%3E%28%29) constructor code?

Comment: It's just a String that contains zero characters.

Comment: (And comparing to an empty String is just a more expensive way to check if the String length is zero.)

Comment: @MichaelT That won't tell me what the machine is doing at runtime:  how is this represented internally, not how its represented in Java Source.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no such thing as "the empty string character". A character is always a UTF-16 code unit, and there's no "empty" code unit. There's "an empty string" which is represented exactly the same way as any other string:

- A `char[]` reference
- An index into that `char[]`
- A length

In this case, the length would be 0. The `char[]` reference could *potentially* be a reference to an empty char array, which could *potentially* be shared between all instance of `String` which have a length of 0.

(Code such as `substring` *could* be implemented by detecting 0-length requests and always returning the same reference to an empty string, but I'm not aware of implementations doing that.)

Comment: `The char[] reference could potentially be a reference to an empty char array` what do you mean by potentially? As in undefined results? Or as in "It can be seen as" (on a phone; cant test right now)

Comment: @VinceEmigh: Well it doesn't matter, as it's an implementation detail... but it *could* refer to a `char[]` which is non-empty.

Comment: So basically... `char[] foo = {};` in C?

Comment: No, because String is a class in Java, it would have a field which could be a zero-length char array. @JonSkeet is just saying it doesn't have to be as long as externally it is treated that way. All "" would likely be treated as the same object because of how Java stores String constants.

Comment: @avgvstvs: Well that's how you could get an empty `char[]`, but that's not the same as a `String`.

Comment: @Jyro117 Hmm... I'm not quite communicating myself I think.  At some point, Java code gets executed (in my case) as x86 instructions.  The `""` sequence in Java is going to get represented *somehow.*  What it sounds like we're saying is that it'll ultimately be a memory layout for a string but the defining difference is likely the length of the string, for most implementations.

Comment: That all depends on the JVM implementation and the Java language makes no requirement on how it works under the covers. The JVM specification (different than the JLS specification) would give more details, but even then the exact layout in the JVM could be anything really. A common and likely method would be to have a pointer from the String object to a char[] object which would have a 0 length property and no elements.

Comment: @avgvstvs: It should behave in all ways like any other `String` object - it just happens to have a length of 0.